# What's the use case for throwing a non-Error object?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, exception

In JS you can `throw new Error()`, `throw 'foo'` or even `throw null`.

Why would you want to throw a non-`Error` instance?  I don't mean objects that inherit from `Error`--I mean other random objects or primitives.

Comment: Who knows? Maybe somebody might design a system that way. What difference does it make?

Comment: I think this question may be better suited at Programmers.SE. (Still, tbh, I'm really curious about this too.)

Comment: throwing a string still shows the string in the console...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, and I suggest to ask this questions in [programmers.se]

Comment: @Krumia this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @Alpha see above ^^^

Comment: @gnat, others: I'm not sure where to ask this if not here.  I am not looking for opinions, or why one way is better than the other; I'm looking for explicit use-cases.

Comment: Nowhere at Stack Exchange I'm afraid.
["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @gnat Thanks. I don't fully agree but I understand the reasons. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: When you await a promise that rejects with a value that is not an error you might want to re-throw in your catch clause ...

Answer (score 2):

`throw` just [throws an arbitrary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw).  It is not connected to the [`Error` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) in any way; you can `throw` any expression.

But it's probably a better idea to inherit from the Error object, which is exactly what the other standard built-in errors do:

[**EvalError**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/EvalError)
Creates an instance representing an error that occurs regarding the global function eval().

[**InternalError**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/InternalError) 
Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when an internal error in the JavaScript engine is thrown. E.g. "too much recursion".

[**RangeError**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RangeError)
Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a numeric variable or parameter is outside of its valid range.

[**ReferenceError**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError)
Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when de-referencing an invalid reference.

[**SyntaxError**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError)
Creates an instance representing a syntax error that occurs while parsing code in eval().

[**TypeError**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError)
Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a variable or parameter is not of a valid type.

[**URIError**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/URIError)
Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when encodeURI() or decodeURI() are passed invalid parameters.

All of these objects prototypically inherit from the Error object, so while it's legal to throw any arbitrary object, it probably makes more sense to throw the Error object or an object that inherits from Error, just like Javascript itself does.

There are several examples of the proper way to do this at [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, which was basically "why would you throw a string or `null`?"  The subtext being that primitives (or other non-`Error` objects), when thrown, do not provide things like stack traces.

Comment: @boneskull what if somebody doesn't want/need a stack trace? Capturing a stack trace is relatively expensive.

Comment: @boneskill: You would throw a string or a null if you wanted to be sloppy, basically.